# Python Pandas - How to get group by counts by values from multiple columns with multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, split, pandas-groupby

My data includes a few variables holding data from multi-answer questions. These are stored as string (comma separated) and aren't ordered by value.

I need to run different counts across 2 or more of these variables at the same time, i.e. get the frequencies of each combination of their unique values.

I also have a second dataframe with the available codes for each variable

```
df_meta['a']['Categories'] = ['1', '2', '3','4']
df_meta['b']['Categories'] = ['1', '2']
```

If this is my data

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["1,3","1"],["3","1,2"],["1,3,2","1"],["3,1","2,1"]]),
                  columns=['a', 'b'])


index  a      b     
1      1,3    1
2      3      1,2
3      1,3,2  1
4      3,1    2,1
```

Ideally, this is what the output would look like

```
a  b   count
1  1   3
1  2   1
2  1   1
2  2   0
3  1   4
3  2   2
4  1   0
4  2   0
```

Although if I it's not possible to get the zero-counts, this would be just fine

```
a  b   count
1  1   3
1  2   1
2  1   1
3  1   4
3  2   2
```

So far, I got the counts for each of these variables individually, by using split and value_counts

```
df["a"].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().value_counts()
3    4
1    3
2    1

df["b"].str.split(',',expand=True).stack().value_counts()
1    4
2    2
```

But I can't figure how to group by them, because of the differences in the indexes.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2["a"] = df["a"].str.split(',',expand=True).stack()
df2["b"] = df["b"].str.split(',',expand=True).stack()
df2.groupby(['a','b']).size()

a  b
1  1    3
3  1    1
   2    1
```

Is there a way to adjust the groupby to only count the instances of the first index or another way to count the unique combinations more efficiency?

I can alternatively iterate through all codes using the df_meta dataframe, but some of the actual variables have 300-400 codes and it's very slow, when I try to cross 2-3 of them and, if it's possible to use groupby or another function, it should work much faster.

Answer (score 0):

First we make your dataframe to start with.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([["1,3","1"],["3","1,2"],["1,3,2","1"], 
     ["3,1","2,1"]]),columns=['a', 'b'])
```

Then split columns to separate dataframes.

```
da = df["a"].str.split(',',expand=True)
db = df["b"].str.split(',',expand=True)
```

Loop through all rows and both dataframes. Make temporary dataframes of all compinations and add them to a list.

```
ab = list()
for r in range(len(da)):
    for i in da.iloc[r,:]:
        for j in db.iloc[r,:]:
            if i != None and j != None:
                daf = pd.DataFrame({'a':[i], 'b':[j]})
                ab.append(daf)
```

Concatenate list of temporary dataframes into one new dataframe.

```
 dfn = pd.concat(ab)
```

Groupby with 'a' and 'b' columns and size() gives you the answer.

```
 print(dfn.groupby(['a', 'b']).size().reset_index(name='count'))

   a  b  count
0  1  1      3
1  1  2      1
2  2  1      1
3  3  1      4
4  3  2      2
```